# Storing data before committing to data base, wait for approval of admin

Tags: angularjs, django, database, rest

My issue is the following:

I'm building a mobile app using Ionic framework, so the front end is essentially a single page AngularJS app.  I'm using Django Rest framework as the backend.

In the application, an employee should be able to suggest updates, deletes, or additions to database models.  In my schema, there is a "Contact person" model (which has fields like first_name, last_name, phone_number, etc.), a "GPS Address model" (which has fields like street_name, street_num, city, etc.) and an overarching "Delivery stop" model to which virtually all of the other models relate.

What I need to implement is a system whereby an employee can suggest an edit to an existing object, say a Contact (id: 45, first_name: 'John', phone_number: "435-0000") which has a FK relationship to a Delivery Stop (id: 20, title: "Stop and Shop", notes: "closes at 0600").  The employee wants to update the phone number to "435-0001".  But the update shouldn't be committed to the database until a manager has reviewed the update and approved, or edited the update then approved.

I have a few ideas about how I might do this, but none of them seem as easy as I think it could be.  Does anyone have any suggestions about best practices in this situation?

The application will also include a special manager interface where they can few all suggested updates/edits and approve/reject them.  The client side essentially functions with the Delivery Stop as the primary object, which shows all related items in a tabbed interface (Contacts, Gps addresses, etc.) And each time an edit is suggested by an employee, the appropriate manager will receive an email notification.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If this were my project, I'd save all changes to the same database table but I'd mark a field called "WaitingForApproval" as True.  Then you can create a page for admins showing all the items waiting to be approved and they can either approve or deny them.

When denied, you can either delete that record or mark a field called "Deleted" as true and make sure not to ever show that record unless somebody specifically wants to see deleted records.

Anytime you pull data from the database, you'll want to filter based on WaitingForApproval being true or false (usually false, unless it's specifically for the admin approval page).  This way, you can keep pending changes in the same table without cluttering up the rest of the application.

Or if you already have a lot of queries written in the app that you don't want to change, you can just save these pending changes into a different but identical database table.  When an admin approves it, your back-end code will just copy the data from the PendingChanges table to the Main table.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Dr. Cool.